# Audio track complete

Tags: python, game-engine, audio

it is possible to use Python to signal when an mp3 file, or other audio file, has finished playing/reached their end? I know how to play them, as per the BGE code below, but don't how do I check if the are finished?

```
sound = aud.Factory('audio.mp3') #loads mp3 or wav file  
if not 'play' in ow: #will play sound only once 
     ow['device'] = aud.device() 
     ow['device'].play(sound)
     ow['play'] = 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There's a status property: [aud.Handle.status](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/aud.html#aud.Handle.status)

You could check it in regular intervals until the status changes to `AUD_STATUS_STOPPED` or `AUD_STATUS_INVALID`, see the [API docs](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_70a_release/aud.html#aud.AUD_STATUS_INVALID).